# About a minimum-norm problem.

Tags: optimization

I am studying on the optimization via vector method. The reference book is Optimization by Vector Method by Luenberg.

I have trouble in understanding the following statement [p.123];

We consider the unknown $x^*$ in a dual space $X^*$ and express the contraints in the form:
$$\langle y_1,x^*\rangle=c_1 , \cdots , \langle y_n,x^*\rangle=c_n$$

If $\bar{x}^*$ is any vector satisfying the contraints, we have

$$d = \min_{\langle y_i,x^* \rangle=c_i}|| x^* || = \min_{m^*\in M^+}|| \bar{x}^*-m^* ||$$

where $M$ denotes the space generated by the $y_i$'s and $M^+$ is the orthogonoal complement of $M$.

My question is because the second equility holds.

Can you explain the reason for

$$\min_{\langle y_i,x^*\rangle=c_i}|| x^* || = \min_{m^*\in M^+}|| \bar{x}^*-m^* ||$$

not for

$$\min_{\langle y_i,x^*\rangle=c_i}|| x^* || = \min_{\bar{x}^*  \in X^*}|| \bar{x}^* ||$$

Thank you ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially just reformulating the problem. It is an exercise in basic linear algebra to show that if $\bar x^*$ is a particular solution to the constraint equations, then the entire solution space is give by $\bar x^* + M^\perp$. That is:

$$
\langle y_i,x^*\rangle = c_i \Leftrightarrow x^*-\bar{x}^*\in M^\perp \Leftrightarrow x^*=\bar{x}^*-m^*, \ m^*\in M^\perp
$$

Your alternative statement is wrong because $\bar x^*$ should not be a variable that you minimize over. Strictly speaking, $\min_{\bar{x}^*  \in X^*}|| \bar{x}^* ||=0$, which is unrelated to the original problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I misunderstood $\bar{x}^*$.

Comment: You're welcome!